# Rails update all records through method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, geocoding

I've updated my event model with two attributes : latitude: float ,longitude: float.
I've already recorded for each entry the address attribute and I'm using the "geocoder" gem (http://rubydoc.info/gems/geocoder/) to retrieve (lat,long) from address.

the model is very simple :

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  geocoded_by :location   # can also be an IP address
  after_validation :geocode
end
```

This works great when I call the "create" action from the controller.

What I'd like to do is updating the latitude and longitude attributes of all existing record of Event.

I know the "update_all" method but the way it works doesn't let me use a method like geocoder.

Any help would be welcome.

Thank you

Comment: How are you getting the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know geocoder works correctly, but you may be able to do the following:

```
$ rails c
Event.find_each(&:save)
```

This will cycle through all your existing events & save them, which I believe will be picked up by the geocoder gem for you to update

Comment: `set_lat_long` is not necessary, I think. That's done automatically by `:geocode`. `before_update` is not necessary either, because he has `after_validation` already. So his model can stay the same. All he has to do is run `Event.find_each(&:save)`.

Comment: My apologies - I'll remove

Comment: Thank you very much, that command will be very useful to me. Perfect